# JavaScript: How can I make sure that this function only returns the fully populated array?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using the Request library. I have an array of URLs (var resources) that I want to populate with the text content of those URLs.

My code looks like this:

```
var resources = [<URL_1>, <URL_2>, <URL_3>, ...];
var resourcesText = resourceToText(resources);

function resourcesToText(resources) {
  var text = [];

  for (var i in resources) {
  request(resources[i], fetch);
  }

  function fetch(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      text.push(body);
    } else {
      console.log('Sorry. I couldn\'t parse that resource. ' + error);
    }
  }

  return text;

};
```

The problem is that resourceToText() returns the array before fetch() has had time to populate it. Thus, resourcesText ends up being empty. I assume higher order functions are meant to deal with this kind of problem but I can't fathom a way to work the callback.

What's the best approach to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: use promise or callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an asynchronous function out of `resourcesToText` by:

**Using an additional callback:**

```
function resourcesToText(resources, callback) {
  var text = [],
      requestCount = resources.length;

  for (var i in resources) {
    request(resources[i], fetch);
  }

  function fetch(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      text.push(body);
    } else {
      console.log('Sorry. I couldn\'t parse that resource. ' + error);
    }
    requestCount--;
    if(requestCount <= 0){
      callback(text);
    }
  }
};
```

Call the callback with your result `text` after you you got all the results of your requests using a counter (`requestCount`).

Now the call to `resourcesToText`looks like:

```
resourcesToText(resources, function(text){
  ...
});
```

**Using deferred/promises**

Instead of using a callback, you could also implement the concept of deferred/promises. There are many libraries out there, such as q (https://github.com/kriskowal/q)